# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Float' Error in swift

Tags: swift, floating-point, option-type

Given:

```
var conv_factor: String?
var standard_rate_in_usd: Double?
```

now I need a Float value

```
var floatVal: Float?

if let priceVal = Float(indexData.standard_rate_in_usd!),
   let convVal = Float((conversion_factor?.conv_factor)!) {
     floatVal = (priceVal * convVal)
}
```

then error: how to fix and get final value in float

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Float'

Comment: `Double` to `Float` conversion never fails, so there's no need for the result to be optional. As the error message explains, the result is just `Float`, not `Float?`. Hence, there's no need to do a conditional binding, if you're going to be force unwrapping everything in the middle anyway

Comment: As an aside, avoid suffixes like `val`. They're just useless noise. There's almost nothing you could name in a Swift program that _isn't_ a value, of some kind or another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a pretty random mix of force unwrapping and conditional wrapping here, so it's not really clear what it is you're trying to achieve.

If you're asserting that none of these values can be nil and you're going to force unwrap in some parts, then just force unwrap it all. A construct like `a?.b!` doesn't make any sense. Just do `a!.b` (assuming `b` itself is non-optional).

If you're going down the "dangerous" route, than it might look like:

```
let floatVal = Float(indexData.standard_rate_in_usd * conversion_factor!.conv_factor)
```

If you want to do conditional binding instead, then it would make sense to do:

```
let floatVal: Float

if let price = indexData.standard_rate_in_usd,
   let conversionFactorString = conversion_factor?.conv_factor,
   let conversionFactor = Float(conversionFactorString) {
    floatVal = Float(price) * conversionFactor)
} else {
    // TODO: decide what the fallback behaviour should be
}
```

Comment: when i use condition binding then in this line of your code `floatVal = Float(price * conversionFactor)` got error `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Double'`

Comment: @swiftdoubts Oh I see, it was a string. That's odd. Why are you storing a `conversionFactor` as a `String`? The only way you could ever use it is by parsing it out into a `Double` or `Float`. But if you're going to need to do that every time you need to use it, why not just do it once instead, and store `conversionFactor: Double`? Anyhow, I made an edit to fit this odd data model as-is

Comment: @swiftdoubts This question might answer your question at face value, but you should really reevaluate how what data types you're storing and when you do your conversions to and from string. You're probably dealing with much more complexity than is actually necessary, just from that alone